# Unir duas tabelas com PHP e recuperar os dados no mesmo elemento select do html

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

Estou tentando listar no mesmo elemento `select` do `html` os resultados da consulta de tabelas diferentes, porém não estou conseguindo.
Segue abaixo o código para que alguém possa me dizer onde estou errando.

```php
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Selecione a turma:</label>
    <select name="id_disciplina_turma_facul">
        <?php
            $consulta = \MySql::conectar()->prepare("SELECT tb_turma_facul.id_turma_facul as turma,
                                                 tb_turma_facul.id_disciplina_turma_facul,

                                                tb_disciplina_facul.id_discip_facul,
                                                tb_disciplina_facul.nome_discip_facul as dnome,                                                   
                                                 tb_turma_facul.id_professor_turma_facul,
                                                 tb_professor_facul.nome_professor as pnome

                                                   FROM tb_turma_facul

                                          INNER JOIN (tb_disciplina_facul, tb_professor_facul)

                                          ON (tb_turma_facul.id_disciplina_turma_facul =
                                          tb_disciplina_facul.id_discip_facul 

                                          AND tb_turma_facul.id_professor_turma_facul =
                                          tb_professor_facul.cpf_professor)");


            $consulta->execute();
            $consulta = $consulta->fetchAll();
            foreach ($consulta as $key => $value) {
        ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $value['dnome'] ?>">
                <?php echo $value['pnome']; ?>
            </option>

        <?php } ?>

    </select>
</div><!--form-group-->

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="acao" value="Matricular em turma">
</div><!--form-group-->
```

As colunas das tabelas estão descritas abaixo.
Sendo, que a tabela `turma` possui as **chaves estrangeiras** das tabelas `disciplina` e `professor`.

Colunas da tabela `tb_disciplina_facul`:

> - `id_discip_facul`
> - `nome_discip_facul`
> - `carga_horaria_discip_facul`

Colunas da tabela `tb_professor_facul`:

> - `nome_professor`
> - `endereco_professor`
> - `complemento_professor`
> - `cep_professor`
> - `bairro_professor`
> - `cidade_professor`
> - `estado_professor`
> - `telefone_professor`
> - `formacao_professor`
> - `titulacao_professor`

Colunas da tabela `tb_turma_facul`:

> - `id_turma_`
> - `id_disciplina_turma_facul`
> - `id_professor_turma_facul`

Comment: Sao quantas tabelas amigo?eu posso fazer um exemplo basico e voce adapta em quantos casos achar melhor

Comment: Observe que as colunas de cada tabela está descrito abaixo do código, dessa forma você poderá se basear para ficar semelhante a minha.

Comment: São 3 tabelas, a primeira das disciplinas, a segunda dos professores e a terceira chama-se turma. Essa última possuirá as chaves estrangeiras das duas primeiras.

Answer (score 0):

Se as colunas descritas estão fieis ao que se encontra no seu banco de dados, você tem dois erros de digitação em seu select: **id_turma_** está como **id_turma_facul** e **id_discip_facul** está como **id_disciplina_facul**.

Fiz essas adaptação e obtive o resultado desejado.

```
SELECT 
  tb_turma_facul.id_turma_facul as turma,
  tb_turma_facul.id_disciplina_turma_facul,
  tb_disciplina_facul.id_discip_facul,
  tb_disciplina_facul.nome_discip_facul as dnome,                                                   
  tb_turma_facul.id_professor_turma_facul,
  tb_professor_facul.nome_professor as pnome
FROM tb_turma_facul
   INNER JOIN (tb_disciplina_facul, tb_professor_facul)
ON (tb_turma_facul.id_disciplina_turma_facul = tb_disciplina_facul.id_discip_facul 
AND tb_turma_facul.id_professor_turma_facul = tb_professor_facul.cpf_professor)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O PHP também teve sucesso no resultado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Resolveu o problema, mudei apenas id_disciplina_facul para id_discip_facul. Em relação a outra coluna, o nome é id_turma_facul mesmo, pois fui eu que coloquei o nome incompleto.